# Why is this Avg function not executing in my program?

Tags: c++, function, oop

I made a basic oop program in which there are 3 functions, now 2 functions are being executed but the last one, the Avg function is not being executed.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
 class Marks
 {
  public:
  int n,sum,avg;
  int urdu,english,math;

   void in()
   {
    cout<<"Enter Marks Of Urdu"<<endl;
    cin>>urdu;
    cout<<"Enter Marks Of English"<<endl;
    cin>>english;
    cout<<"Enter Marks Of Maths"<<endl;
    cin>>math;

   }
   void Sum()
   {
   sum=urdu+english+math;
   cout<<"Sum Of Subjects = "<<sum<<endl;
   }

   float Avg(int sum)
   {
    return sum/3;

   }

 };
int main ()
 {
  Marks M;
  M.in();
  M.Sum();
  M.Avg(M.sum);

 }
```

Seems that only the functions that aren't returning any value are being performed. How do I perform a function that returns a value?

Comment: How do you know it's not being executed? Note that since you discard the result and it has no side effects, the function can just be optimized out.

Comment: Or maybe it is executing, but you don't see anything because there's no print? You want a debugger.

Comment: well, it's not returning the value in output

Comment: Can you point your finger at the exact line of the shown code which you expect to produce the missing "output"?

Comment: Where do you print the result of the `Avg` function? Do you print it in the `Avg` function itself? Do you print it after you have called it? Some simple [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) would go a long way here.

Comment: well, i want to return the average

Comment: `return` is not the same as `std::cout<<`.

Comment: Wow, I remember when I wrote my first program I also didn't output the result, and I was very cross at compiler - doesn't it understand that if I ask it to add 5 and 7 I really would like to know what the result is?

Comment: @Some programmer dude is that necessary? how do I do that?

Comment: By the way, once you figure out that you never ever asked compiler to do anything with the result, `sum/3` will not give you floating point average with `int` sum.

Comment: And it returned the average. Again, which exact line of the code should be producing the result you are expecting? You called `Avg()`. And `Avg()` returned. What are you missing?

Comment: @François Andrieux  well, then could you please tell me what do i need to do to print the value?

Comment: Remember, compilers are pretty stupid. They create a program that does exactly what you say in the code, not anything else. If you don't say "print this value" in the code, the program simply won't print anything.

Comment: The exact same thing you did to print all the other values, of course.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik i want to print the value of average

Comment: @zeplika "well, it's not returning the value in output" - of course it is not producing any output, because you are not printing anything. You are just calling a function (which itself does not print anything) and then discarding the result of the function call (which obviously also doesn't print anything). How you'd ever expect a call to that function to produce any output is beyond me.

Comment: So, what's stopping you from writing the code that prints it?

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik can you please show me? sorry i know i sound stupid

Comment: No, you are not stupid, you already wrote the code to print other values that your program handles. So, write some more code that does exactly what you wrote, already.

Comment: @zeplika you seem to have no troubles printing `sum`, why can't you print `average` in the similar manner?

Comment: @JesperJuhl A lot of interpreted languages does that. If I type 3+4 in R console, I'll see 7. Also, everyone started to learn at one point, it's quite normal that newbies forget about doing certain things or think their programs should work in some particular manner...

Comment: sorry i didn't really study much about functions so i didn't know that id have to cout the value too. well, my problem is solved now. Thanks for helping guys and sorry for wasting your time with this small thing

Comment: @zeplika Thing to remember is that computers don't 'do what you want', they do what you tell them. If you keep on thinking that the computer is smart enough to figure out what you want then you're going to have a lot of disappointment.

Comment: A pure function is one that has not side-effects. It takes input and produces output. If you ignore the output, there is no observable difference between calling the function and not calling the function. A compiler is free to replace one program with another program, as long as it doesn't change the observable output. With that in mind, why are you surprised, that your compiler doesn't produce code that has not observable effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not doing anything with the value it returns, so calling the function doesn't actually have an effect.

In `main`, do something to use it:

```
int main ()
{
  Marks M;
  M.in();
  M.Sum();
  float answer = M.Avg(M.sum);
  std::cout << "The answer is " << answer << '\n'; 
}
```

Also, it should be noted that you're using integer division when calculating `Avg`:

```
float Avg(int sum) {
  return sum / 3; // This is integer division b/c both arguments are integers
}
```

Make one of the arguments a `float` so you get a floating-point answer:

```
float Avg(int sum) {
  return sum / 3.0f; 
}
```

Comment: right, thanks a lot. it worked